# How can I programmatically change each item of a RecyclerView all at once? (See post)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, selection

everyone.

I'm currently writing a vocabulary app ("Vocabulator) by using a room database and a RecyclerView to display the information.
My problem is that the way I implemented the feature to delete data from the RecyclerView (and the database) does **not** work on a **dataset>10 items**.

[gif of how the delete function works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6if8T.gif)

On the gif you can see that whenever an item is longClicked, a radio button for each item appears.
Upon clicking the button, the respective item is removed from the RecyclerView (and the db).

As you can see, this works on this very small dataset, but once I add more items the app starts to crash when performing the **longClick**.

Under the hood, it is implemented using a for loop to reiterate over each item like this:

```
   @Override
public void onLongItemClick(int adapterPosition) {
    //wordList.get(position);

    // Show radio buttons
    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getItemCount(); i++)
    {
        vh = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i);
        v = ((RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder) vh).getView();
        rb = v.findViewById(R.id.delete_selector);
        if (rb.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE)
        {
            rb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
            rb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
    longClicked = true;
}
```

I **can imagine** this isn't among the most performant lines of code ever written.

However, that's the solution a beginner like me came up with.

I'd love to implement my delete feature in terms of its functionality exactly as demonstrated in the gif.

However, I can't find a way to make this work.

Can you give me any advice on the issue? :)

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Whenever the app crashes, you should get an error log / stack trace printed out in the "Run" section (Bottom left of android studio), providing that here will help clarify your problem, but chances are if you google the error you will already find an answer

Comment: Thank you. This helps a lot. I haven't really noticed the stack trace before. It seems like I'm invoking a method on a null object reference. I can work with that. Thank you!

Comment: // Update: So I found out that the problem was me misunderstanding how findViewHolderForAdapterPosition works, as well as getting wrong how the ViewHolder and the RecyclerView.Adapter work together. I could solve this problem by utilizing RecyclerView.Adapter **onBindViewHolder** the way it is supposed to be used and let it decide if the RadioButton should be visible when binding new Views to the recycled ViewHolders. Via a simple onClick Listener I would then call Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), so the adapter would therefore rebind every viewholder, this time with visible radio button. :)